# File.CreateText - Access Denied

Tags: c#, file-io, permission-denied, createfile

I recently spent a while trying to figure out what permissions were needed to get this statement to work:

```
if (!File.Exists(path)) 
{
    // Create a file to write to. 
    using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path)) 
    {
        sw.WriteLine("Hello");
        sw.WriteLine("And");
        sw.WriteLine("Welcome");
    }   
}
```

I eventually have "Special Permissions" to "Everyone" which should have solved the problem.  Sadly it didn't, it may actually be a bug?

The following works:

```
if (!File.Exists(_logFilePath))
{
    using (var fs = File.Create(_logFilePath))
    {
        using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
        {
             sw.WriteLine("Hello");
             sw.WriteLine("And");
             sw.WriteLine("Welcome");
        }
    }
}
```

Theoretically identical (I think), but I couldn't get the first to work.

Comment: I think it's because the code isn't quite identical (you're declaring a new thing in the second snippet, but aren't declaring anything `new` in the first one).

Comment: really don't think it's a bug, can you please show the exception you get

Comment: What "doesn't work"? What is _logFilePath?

Comment: @llan321 - File.CreateText is a static method so no "new" is required.

Comment: @Guru Stron - The exception was a "Access Denied" error, do you need the full exception?

Comment: @JeffRSon _logFilePath is a string which has the location of my log file, using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(path)) throws and exception with "Access Denied"

Comment: What exactly (content) is `path` and `_logFilePath`?

Comment: @Talon, yes it could help

Comment: @JeffRSon var _logFilePath = "C:\temp\IndexerService\LogFiles\IndexerLog.txt";  The folder does exist (i copied into windows explorer to make sure).

Answer (score -1):

I think the **path** variable is wrong. 
Make sure you've also entered the **file name** in the path.